# Issue with date in Apex Maps

Tags: apex, map, date

I am populating a map indexed by enddate. When I print the date property in apex before storing the map as key it prints yyyy:MM:DD 00:00:00. When I store it in the map it only print yyyy:MM:DD. Because of that, when I retrive Map values based on an enddate, I cannot access the value associated to the key in the map.

**Here is what I am actually tring to do:**
I need to create invoices and invoicelineitems based on start date and term(no of months) of the order. 
So I have indexed invoiceline Items by enddate in a map in apex. So I can create 1 invoce for every endate in map , then query for invoice Id and enddate and retreive the invoicelines from map based on enddate. The map now cannot find the invoice lines as the format has changed. The endate__c field from query is   (YYYY:MM:DD 00:00:00) and the map stored (YYYY:MM:DD). I printed the apex class member enddate before storing in the map which prints (YYYY:MM:DD 00:00:00) but when I put it into the map and print the map it only shows (YYYY:MM:DD).

Sorry Unable to post the code.
Here is a snippet from my execute anonymous.

```
Date endDate = date.today().addMonths(1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1);
endDate= date.newInstance(endDate.year(),endDate.month(),endDate.day());
system.debug('-->'+endDate);
map<date,string> mymap= new map<date,string>{endDate=>'string'};
system.debug(json.serialize(mymap));
```

> 13:00:38.15 (15903802)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|-->2017-05-31 00:00:00
>
> 13:00:38.15 (16511592)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|{"2017-05-31":"string"}

Comment: May be I can do some date manipulation before retrieving using the date. But is there any other way for indexing by date and retreiving later on.

Comment: Please review [ask]. Without seeing your code the proof of concept based on your question below is what can be offered

Comment: You will need to post some code that reproduces the issue (should be pretty straight forward). It does not have to be your exact code in your codebase, but something that is reproducible in general. If you can't  come up with reproducible code then I suggest that you consider it is not what you think it is.

Comment: Updated my question and added execute anonymous snippet.

Comment: see my updated answer. It still works just fine. I am guessing either you did not attempt to get the value from the map and were assuming that because of the debug it would not work or you are using some external system that you did not mention in your question

Comment: I tried to get the value from the map. I got an error attempt to deference null object. I am not using external system.  When I asserted false and printed the the map and date, the date shows up with (YYYY:MM:DD 00:00:00) and none of the key values in the map would show 00:00:00 part of the date.

Comment: I can only go by the code you posted. you did not put any of that. Put reproducible code if you want an answer to your specific problem. see my answer for proof that it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Not so sure the issue is where you think it is. The only way to know for sure how to help is to see your implementation

The below example uses a date (Opportunity CloseDate which is of type Date) as a key and shows the same behavior when debugging. Additionally it shows that the value and key are able to be retrieved

```
Date d = [select CloseDate From Opportunity Limit 1].CloseDate;
System.debug(d);
Map<Date,String> tmp = New Map<Date,String>();
tmp.put(d,'A');
System.debug(tmp);
System.debug(tmp.get(d));
```

**Output**

> 12:52:39.17 (18923192)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|2017-05-22 00:00:00
>
> 12:52:39.17 (19140585)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|{2017-05-22 00:00:00=A}
>
> 12:52:39.17 (19205833)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|A

**Using your code (from updated question) it works just fine as well**

```
Date endDate = date.today().addMonths(1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1);
endDate= date.newInstance(endDate.year(),endDate.month(),endDate.day());
system.debug('-->'+endDate);
map<date,string> mymap= new map<date,string>{endDate=>'string'};
string tmpJSON = json.serialize(mymap);

Map<Date,string> newMyMap = (Map<Date,string>)json.deserialize(tmpJSON,Map<Date,string>.class);
System.debug(newMyMap.get(endDate));
System.debug(newMyMap.get(date.parse('05/31/2017')));
```

> 16:18:18.35 (36371211)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|-->2017-05-31 00:00:00
>
> 16:18:18.35 (38421715)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|string
>
> 16:28:16.27 (32419669)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|string

Comment: Firstly thanks for replying . See this snippet in my execute anonymous.Date endDate = date.today().addMonths(1).toStartofMonth().addDays(-1);
endDate= date.newInstance(endDate.year(),endDate.month(),endDate.day());
system.debug('-->'+endDate);
map<date,string> mymap= new map<date,string>{endDate=>'string'};
system.debug(json.serialize(mymap)); 13:00:38.15 (15903802)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|-->2017-05-31 00:00:00 13:00:38.15 (16511592)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|{"2017-05-31":"string"}

Comment: @Venkata - Post it in your question not in a comment please